# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar mis subconsultas?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Hola tengo una duda como poder optimizar mis subconsultas.
Tengo 3 consultas, en uno como condición separados por el `ID_Etapa_vital`.

```
select  Etapa_Vital.ID_Etapa_vital
       , (select count(*) 
            from paciente 
            where paciente.Genero ='Masculino' 
            and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = Etapa_Vital.ID_Etapa_Vital
         ) NumeroDePacientesMasculinos
       , (select count(*)  
            from ong_padma.sesiones 
            inner join paciente on paciente.ID_numero_historia = sesiones.ID_numero_historia
           where paciente.Genero = 'Masculino'
            and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = Etapa_Vital.ID_Etapa_Vital
         ) NumeroDeSesionesConPacientesMasculinos
      ,(select count(*)  from
            (
            select nombre
            from ong_padma.sesiones 
            inner join paciente on paciente.ID_numero_historia = sesiones.ID_numero_historia
            where paciente.Genero = 'Masculino' 
            and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = 1  <------------------------- 
            group by nombre  
            having count(cantidad_sesiones)>2
            ) paciente)Continuadores
  from Etapa_Vital
 where Etapa_Vital.ID_Etapa_Vital = 1; <---------------------------
```

En esta consulta solo obtengo por el `ID_Etapa_vital  1`.

```
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________
|ID_Etapa_vital |NumeroDePacientesMasculinos| NumeroDeSesionesConPacientesMasculinos|continuadores
| --------------| --------------------------|---------------------------------------|-------------------
|  1            |    20                     |          40                           |       10
```

Pero... en realidad quisiera que quede así separado por los `ID_etapa_vital`.

```
________________________________________________________________________________________________________
|ID_Etapa_vital |NumeroDePacientesMasculinos| NumeroDeSesionesConPacientesMasculinos|continuadores
| --------------| --------------------------|---------------------------------------|-------------------
|  1            |    50                     |          80                           |       60
|  2            |    40                     |          10                           |       60
|  3            |    70                     |          300                          |       60
|  4            |    250                    |          800                          |       60
|  5            |    50                     |          30                           |       60
|  6            |    500                    |          800                          |       60
```

leí sobre tablas dinámicas pero no se como poder poder trasladar mis sub consultas.

Comment: Saludos. Así como tienes las subconsultas úsalas después del `FROM Etapa_Vital`y usas `LEFT JOIN`con c/u. omites el 'and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = Etapa_Vital.ID_Etapa_Vital` y similar y ya en el `ON` de c/u lo colocas como corresponda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Relaciona la tercera sub-consulta con la tabla principal, en lugar de esto:

   ```
    and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = 1
   ```

   que siempre te trae los registros de `ID_Etapa_Vital` igual a 1, utiliza:

   ```
    and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = Etapa_Vital.ID_Etapa_Vital
   ```

   lo que hará que, para cada registro de la tabla Etapa_Vital, la sub-consulta haga el cálculo correcto.
2. Quita el `where` de la consulta principal. Este está provocando que traiga solo el registro con *ID* igual a `1`, si lo quitas, traerá todos los de la tabla:

### Edición:

Según comenta el AP, mySQL es incapaz de procesar la referencia a la tabla principal de la consulta en una sub-sub consulta, cosa que no debiera, pero no me sorprende de este motor. Lo que sugiero es que re-escribas esa consulta para tener la referencia un nivel afuera, por ejemplo:

```
select count(*)
  from (select   paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital
               , paciente.ID_numero_historia
               , count(1) Sesiones
          from paciente 
               inner join ong_padma.sesiones on sesiones.ID_numero_historia = paciente.ID_numero_historia
         where paciente.Genero = 'Masculino'
         group by paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital
               , paciente.ID_numero_historia
        having count(1) > 2
       ) a
 where a.ID_Etapa_Vital = Etapa_Vital.ID_Etapa_Vital
```

Al tener la condición, el motor debiera ser capaz de ejecutar la sub-consulta con una eficiencia similar a la anterior. En todo caso, habría que analizar los planes de ejecución de ambas para ver qué hace el motor y buscar una solución en caso que no esté optimizándola adecuadamente.

Comment: el problema es que en la tercera subconsulta utiliza otra consulta dentro de ella para contar es por esa razon que me sale este error

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Etapa_Vital.ID_Etapa_Vital' in 'where clause'

Comment: Edité la respuesta, con la que creo que es la mejor solución para el caso que comentas.

Comment: Gracias si funciono , eres un crack :)